# How to convert a dynamic url to a secure one

Tags: php, user-interface

I have urls similar to this

```
  http://www.somewebsite.com/sub-category/?q=1

  http://www.somewebsite.com/products/?q=1

  http://www.somewebsite.com/product/?q=61
```

but i need to change the url to more secure one so that no one can type some other number and get a product with another id or I dont want anyone to see ?q=1. Someone Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can apply concept of `encoding-decoding`

Comment: Some light reading for you: [`.htaccess` RewriteRule](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a hash like http://www.somewebsite.com/products/?q=1&hash=xxxx

Where the hash is generated using a secret key in the backend. 
Something like this

```
$productID = 1;
$url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/products/?q=".$productID;
$hash = md5("my-secret-key".$productID);
$url .= "&hash=".$hash;
```

And then on your request check that the hash is valid.

```
if(md5("my-secret-key".$_GET['q']) != $_GET['hash']){
    die("Invalid hash");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.Its working . Can i direct the page to home page if someone try to alter the hash...?

Comment: Yes you can just replace the die() with header("Location: /"); exit;

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can always try to type something in the URL and hope you hit something.

You could create a hash out of the product Id for each product and store it in a or the same table where you store your products.

Then you would pass the hash and not the product ID.

It's much harder to guess e.g. 64 chars than to guess one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.